# Second CSS class not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have the following div being rendered to the client, but on IE, the `checked-yes` class is ignored.  If I view the target element in the 'Developer Tools', that class is completely missing from the *Style* panel.  The `shift-item-present` class is attached server side, and the `checked-yes` class client side, depending on the `present` attribute of the parent row, also shown below.

```
<td><div class="shift-item-present checked-yes" jQuery1272958392665="94"/></td>
```

Parent row:

```
<tr class="shift-item" id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_shiftList_ctl01_shiftRow" present="True" shift-id="641" jQuery1272958392665="64">
```

The page works perfectly in FF.  Here is the CSS, both in the same file:

```
.shift-item-present
{
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}

.checked-yes
{
    background-image: url('../Images/Icons/checked-yes-xs.png');
}
```

Comment: I assume CSS isn't applied, can you post that too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support XHTML! Not even IE8. So it doesn't support self-closing elements. Use `<div></div>` not `<div/>`.

Comment: No, it can't. It may be working by chance here, because the `div` is in a `td` by its own, but that does not change the fact that **IE8 does not support self-closing elements**.

Comment: "IE8 can work with it." WRONG! When you think it "works", it's because you're incorrectly sending the XHTML as text/html (not application/xhtml+xml) causing IE (and everyone else) to parse it as HTML anyway. Send it with its proper MIME to allow correct XHTML parsing (and IE to choke on it, giving a Download dialog).

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when IE8 renders the page in Quirks mode. Try to set a correct DOCTYPE.

Comment: What is a correct DOCTYPE?  This is the default one VS generates, which I thought I could assume to be correct.

Comment: May be you will post the whole files or html output? This may helps